# How to get backtrace of external source which generated the signal?

Tags: c, debugging, signals

[Signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) are generated due to various reason. One can easily get the signal number. Do we have a way to get the backtrace of the code which triggered the signal?
If signal is raised within a process then we can look into the code which triggered the signal by putting dumping backtrace from a signal handler or using library like libunwind. 
If I trying to find a way by which a process can find the external source of signal. For example one can run "kill" and send signal to the process. How do we find backtrace or source of these signals.

Comment: [GDB has the ability to detect any occurrence of a signal in your program](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html), as do most debuggers, so I'm not really sure what you're asking here. You should really provide more information on your environment, and what you need to do with this information, etc.

Comment: Do you mean from within the signal handler? [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/) can do it.

Comment: Do you mean a process raises a signal to itself? O.W. the sender of the signal is another process and a backtrace of that would mean?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by others, use GDB, set a breakpoint at the signal handler, and display the backtrace using the [bt](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_42.html) command.

If your program does not take parameters, its easy:

```
> gdb myprogram
> br mySignalHandler
> run
```

When it hits the breakpoint, type bt to get the traceback:

```
> bt
```

If you program needs command line parameters, using the --args option:

```
> gdb --args myprogram param1 param2 etc
> br mySignalHandler
> run
```

And it will stop when it enters your mySignalHandler routine. Type bt to get your backtrace.

This is also very useful for when your code segfaults, but in that case there is no need to set a breakpoint. Segfaulting code stops automatically and then you can type bt to find out where it died.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am working on finding the external event which triggered the signal.

Comment: Is the external event on another processor, or another process on the same processor?

Comment: Signal is raised from the same OS with single or multi processor.

Comment: Ouch. You could try using gdb to set a tracepoint on raise(int sig), but if this signal gets raised a lot then it will be tough to find the process you are looking for. Is the signal that you are looking for commonly raised? If so, your tracepoint will be swamped and someone smarter than me will have to help you.

To set a gdb conditional tracepoint:
(gdb)trace raise if sig=signalName (you are interested in)

If you know the process that is raising it, that will narrow it down and I think that you can set the tracepoint for just that process, but I haven't done it.

Sorry cant help more